# How to draw concentric dotted circles with varying sizes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view that draws concentric circles to fill a screen:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                ForEach((0...50), id: \.self) { index in
                    
                    Path { path in
                        var radius = CGFloat(120 + (index * 30))
                        let center = (x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2)
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + radius, y: center.y))
                        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y), radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: false)
                    }
                    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, dash: [3.0]))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Which look like this when rendered:

[image: concentric circles]

What I'm trying to achieve is for the dashes to be circular dots instead and for their **size** & **spacing** to gradually increase as the circles go outwards. Looking to achieve an end result like this but with the circular shapes overflowing the screen bounds while centered to the screen and also honoring the safe area which currently my circles are not. There are more circular arcs visible in the top half than the bottom. Any help is appreciated.

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Canvas`. Then just apply `.ignoresSafeArea` to paint into the safe area. Like this:

```swift
struct Dots: View {
    let innerRadius: CGFloat
    let radiusStep: CGFloat
    let innerDotSize: CGFloat
    let gapRatio: CGFloat

    init(
        innerRadius: CGFloat = 80,
        radiusStep: CGFloat = 45,
        innerDotSize: CGFloat = 8,
        gapRatio: CGFloat = 2.2
    ) {
        self.innerDotSize = innerDotSize
        self.gapRatio = gapRatio
        self.innerRadius = innerRadius
        self.radiusStep = radiusStep
    }

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let originX = size.width / 2
            let originY = size.height / 2
            let cornerDistance = ((originX * originX) + (originY * originY)).squareRoot()
            let circumference = 2 * CGFloat.pi * innerRadius
            let nDots = Int((circumference / (innerDotSize * (gapRatio + 1))) + 0.5)
            let angleStep = (2.0 * .pi) / Double(nDots)
            var radius = innerRadius
            while radius < cornerDistance {

                // Start at 12 o' clock
                var angle = -Double.pi / 2.0
                let circumference = 2 * CGFloat.pi * radius
                let dotSize = circumference / (CGFloat(nDots) * (1.0 + gapRatio))
                for _ in 0..<nDots {
                    let x = originX + (cos(angle) * radius) - (dotSize / 2)
                    let y = originY + (sin(angle) * radius) - (dotSize / 2)
                    context.fill(
                        Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: dotSize, height: dotSize)),
                        with: .foreground
                    )
                    angle += angleStep
                }
                radius += radiusStep
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Dots()
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image: Dots]

Answer (score 0):

Use `scaleEffect`, `offset`, `rotationEffect` with parameters from a `ForEach` to put all the circles in place.

```
ZStack {
    // for each "ring"...
    ForEach(0..<10) { i in 
        // for each circle in the "ring"...
        // it looks like there are 20 circles in each "ring"
        ForEach(0..<20) { j in 
            // try experimenting by changing the constants
let i = CGFloat(i)
            let circleSize: CGFloat = 16
            let scaleStep = 0.3
            // scale and offset depends on the ring number
            let scale = 1 + i * scaleStep
            // add extra offset if you want the circles to be equally spaced
            //let extra = (i * (2 + (i - 1) * scaleStep) * circleSize) / 2
            let offset = 100 + i * 50// + extra
            // angle doesn't depend on the ring number, but depends on which circle it is in the ring
            let angle = Double(j) * (360 / 20)
            Circle()
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
                // scale, move the circle downwards, and finally rotate
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .offset(y: offset)
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: angle))
        }
    }
}
```

To solve the safe area issue, put the `ZStack` in a `GeometryReader` that ignores safe area:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    ZStack {
        ...
    }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
}.ignoresSafeArea()
```

[image]